# You were right, my friend

Tags: word

Definitely lost a lot of cash that night but silly me just kept on playing - (blackjack)

On many many occasions I chose not to hang around - (lone wolf)

While treasure hunting we found a lot of gold - (lucky)

I really tried to tell the difference between them but it was just too hard - (twins)

Finally we made it happen - (pregnancy)

Back then I thought differently but now I know it's always 180 - (triangle)

Once I started to follow the lords words I began to feel better - (commandments)

---

**What word am i looking for?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the word you are looking for is

> correct

> The word(s) in parentheses each represent a number:
>  The goal in blackjack is to hit **21**.
>  A lone wolf is only **1** wolf.
>  **7** the most commonly known lucky number.
>  Twins consist of **2** people.
>  Pregnancies are (usually) **9** months long.
>  Triangles have **3** sides.
>  There are **10** commandments.
>  Then for each number n, you take the nth letter on the corresponding line.

Comment: Yes, well done!

Comment: The answer is correct.